# For ehcache to store and object is implementing serializable required?

Tags: java, spring, serialization, ehcache

I've encountered some code that is using Spring ehcache. The objects that are being cached do not implement the serializable interface.

```
class MyObj(){

}

List<MyObj> = new ArrayList<MyObj>
```

So even though ArrayList implements serializable should'nt MyObj also implement serializable for ehcache to work correctly ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objects used in Ehcache only need to implement `Serializable` if you need to store the cache on disk or are using cache replication.

Check out the section

> Supports Object or Serializable caching

from [this](http://ehcache.org/about/features) documentation

Comment: I visited the link provided above and tried to search the sections named 'Support Object' and even 'Serializable caching', but there was none. Would you mind to edit your answer and provide the missing reference / information? Thanks

Comment: You are correct that the link is broken. I also tried to find the passage where the `Serializable` part is mentioned and failed. Should I be able to find the relevant documentation I will update the answer